# rospack cannot find package after installing through apt-get

Tags: ros, moveit, packages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I want to use ROS MoveIt! libraries to control a robot arm. So, I installed MoveIt! with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-moveit-full
```

Then ran:

```
source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
```

Inspecting /opt/ros/indigo/include, there are now various folders with the prefix "moveit". However, if I run the command:

```
rospack find moveit
```

It prints out:

```
package 'moveit' not found
```

The same happens if I try to find ros-indigo-moveit-full.

So, why can ROS not find this package?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209779/rospack-cannot-find-package-after-installing-through-apt-get/) by [Karnivaurus](https://answers.ros.org/users/21659/karnivaurus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2015-05-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi ,there,you package find is not correct, moveit is not the package name,you need to find the package in the following such as:

```
moveit_ros_planning
moveit_fake_controller_manager    moveit_ros_planning_interface
moveit_msgs                       moveit_ros_robot_interaction
moveit_planners_ompl              moveit_ros_visualization
moveit_ros_benchmarks             moveit_ros_warehouse
moveit_ros_benchmarks_gui         moveit_setup_assistant
moveit_ros_manipulation           moveit_simple_controller_manager
moveit_ros_move_group             moveit_visual_tools
moveit_ros_perception
```

---

Originally posted by [manipulator](https://answers.ros.org/users/22010/manipulator/) with karma: 48 on 2015-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2